# Ensuring MySQL connection works in PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, scope, mysqli

I have code with the following form:

```
<?php
function doSomething{
  //Do stuff with MySQL
  $con->tralalala();
}
$con = connectToDatabase;//This would actually be a line or two.
doSomething();
?>
```

This (type of) code doesn't work, because doSomething() doesn't have a connection to the database.  Can anyone explain why not?  I create the $con connection *before* I call doSomething().  So why does the function act as if there's no connection?

Is there any way to fix this, short of passing the connection into the function like doSomething($con)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you probably need to tell it to look in the global scope:

```
     function doSomething()
     {
         global $con;
         $con->tralalala();
     }
```