# PHP - Error - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, system

Does anyone know what might be going wrong? I have tried everything, searched everything but found nothing. There might just be a typo that I can't see.

Function class

```
function validate_credentials($user_name, $user_password) {
    $user_name      = mysql_real_escape_string($user_name);
    $user_password  = sha1($user_password);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = '{$user_name}' AND `user_password` = '{$user_password}'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) !== 1) {
        return false;
    }

    return mysql_result($result, 0);
}
```

Class

```
include('./core/user.inc.php');

if (isset($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_password'])) {
    if (($user_id = validate_credentials($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_password'])) != false) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

        header('Location: ./messages/');

        die();
    }
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="./sign-in.php">
    <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="password" name="user_password" id="user_password" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="submit" placeholder="Confirm Password" value="Sign in" />
</form>
```

Comment: What happens when you run it? Any error message?

Comment: Im using Google Chrome and it just says 'Server error'.

Comment: **I found out that 'if (($user_id = validate_credentials($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_password'])) != false) {' is causing the error**

Comment: Does your script do the redirection to ./messages ?

Comment: You'll most likely need to turn on error reporting or check the log to see if anything has been reported there. It may be enough to call `error_reporting(E_ALL);` right after the PHP tag in the page. Also, did you call `session_start` somewhere?

Comment: No redirection occurs, just the error.

Comment: I don't think 'Server error' is caused by your php script, can you run a simple php code?

Comment: Yeah, but if I remove 'if (($user_id = validate_credentials($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_password'])) != false) {' from the PHP code, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I did also call     session_start();

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$user_id = validate_credentials($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_password'])

if($user_id){
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;  blahblah}
```

Comment: Are you sure the password is inserted and encrypted with sha1?Also use some other browser.

Comment: Oh,but shouldn't the function contain the connection to mysql,otherwise that select won`t work.

Comment: I also used Safari, this password is defiantly encrypted with SHA1.

Comment: Making the function contain the MySQL connection didn't do anything.

Comment: By the way i'm using MAMP on a Mac with PHP 5.4.4 using XCache, that may help.

Comment: I`m not sure it`s the case but shouldn't you clear the cache after making code changes.And did you use global for connecting in the function? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394113/ensuring-mysql-connection-works-in-php-function

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate_credentials($user_name, $user_password) {
   $user_name = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($user_name));
   $user_password = trim(mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($user_password)));

   $result = @mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_name = '".$user_name."' AND user_password = '".$user_password."'");

   if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 1) {
      return false;
   }
   return mysql_result($result, 0);

}

include('./core/user.inc.php');

if (isset($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['user_password'])) {
   $user_id = validate_credentials($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_password']);
   if ($user_id) {
      $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
      header('Location: ./messages/');
      die();
   }
}
```

Comment: I got it, the script doesn't like accessing a function from another class.

Comment: You checked $user_id variable is it empty?